# Unreal Engine 4: Multiple cast on actor , in AI blueprint

Tags: scripting, unreal-engine4, blueprint

I've made in this morning an AI , who follow target points. How can i make another AI in my game? Is it possible to duplicate AI blueprint , and the cast to it? This is my bp: [bp1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vY6qP.jpg)

I've tried to copy this , and make reference to another AI , with sequence ,but is working just first car(AI) , 2nd is not moving : [bp2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OFgE.jpg)

Thank you for help , if someone need more details , i will give u! :)

Comment: Never place space before comma :)

Comment: ok...i don't understand why...

Comment: this is a [rule](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4645/is-it-ever-correct-to-have-a-space-before-a-question-or-exclamation-mark) in English

Answer (score 0):

**Steps**

1. Remove Sequence node and second Cast to SedanController node.
2. Connect Cast to AISedan Cast Failed pin to Cast to AISedan2.

That should resolve your issue. I also recommend to carefully examine [UE4 BehaviorTree guide](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/AI/BehaviorTrees/QuickStart/) and [UE4 Blueprint Visual Scripting guide](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Blueprints/).

Comment: This don't save my problem , i have errors ,and the other AI is not tracking the points ,the AI go anywhere on the map http://imgur.com/a/XZEz9 , this is the blue print for moving the car http://imgur.com/a/RNlmr

Comment: In that case provide more details in your description. Your AIControllers, BehaviorTrees other classes that you use. From what you've provided I found only one problem and I pointed it out.